# What is Zone Hashing in Natural Language Processing?

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval

Has anyone in the NLP field heard of the term *Zone Hashing*? From what I hear, zone hashing is the process of iterating through a document and extracting sentences. An accumulation of sentences is then hashed, and the process continues for the next *n* sentences...

I haven't found any references to this on Google, so I'm wondering if it goes by a different name. It should be related to measuring text similarity/nearness.

Perhaps it refers to locality sensitive hashing?

Comment: It seems more related to Information Retrieval than actual NLP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, "zone hashing" is not a well established concept in the NLP as a discipline. It is just a simple concept used in some algorithms (related to NLP). The only one I know, which uses it is a `Sphinx` search server, and here, "zone hashing" is simply "hashing of objects called zones", where "zone" is described as follows:

> Zones can be formally defined as follows. Everything between an
>   opening and a matching closing tag is called a span, and the aggregate
>   of all spans corresponding sharing the same tag name is called a zone.
>   For instance, everything between the occurrences of < H1 > and < /H1 > in
>   the document field belongs to H1 zone.
>
> Zone indexing, enabled by index_zones directive, is an optional
>   extension of the HTML stripper. So it will also require that the
>   stripper is enabled (with html_strip = 1). The value of the
>   index_zones should be a comma-separated list of those tag names and
>   wildcards (ending with a star) that should be indexed as zones.
>
> Zones can nest and overlap arbitrarily. The only requirement is that
>   every opening tag has a matching tag. You can also have an arbitrary
>   number of both zones (as in unique zone names, such as H1) and spans
>   (all the occurrences of those H1 tags) in a document. Once indexed,
>   zones can then be used for matching with the ZONE operator, see
>   Section 5.3, “Extended query syntax”.

And hashing of these structures is used in the traditional sense to speed up search and lookup. I am not aware of any "deeper" meaning.

> Perhaps it refers to locality sensitive hashing?

Locality sensitive hashing is a probabilistic method for multi dimensional data, I do not see any deeper connections to the zone hashing then fact that both use hash functions.

Comment: Thank you, lejlot. My ultimate goal is to see how this can be used in NLP for measuring similarity between texts, and to find other techniques that can be used also. Do you happen to know of any other techniques off the top of your head?

Comment: There are hundreds of such methods, search papers for "string similarity metrics", "conceptual similarity metrics" or "document similary metrics". They range from the single metrics (like Hamming/Jaccard), to text kernels (also worth searching) - based on both text (string kernel) and/or meaning (wordnet kernel)